# where can I find documentation for specific version

Tags: angular, primeng

I use primeng UI components 1.1.1 version for angular. But on their site (https://www.primefaces.org/primeng) I can find documentation only for the latest version.
Where I can find documentation for specific older versions? I do not want to upgrade to the latest version as I can corrupt something in my project. Besides new versions of the components are released quite often.
Now with my version I have problems with development (get some errors) as I do not know which features are supported (as I can only reference to the latest version on their site).

Comment: Ok. Both things have been corrected.

Comment: Cool, thanks. Good luck with developing with PrimeNG

Comment: I'm also interested in finding documentation for version 2

Comment: Documentation for primeng version: step 1) download version.  step 2) cd to the version and run npm install and ng serve.  step 3) navigate to localhost:4200

Comment: Versions correspond to version of angular.  If you’re looking for an angular2 version, start with 2.0.x of primeng.  ng serve will not work with version 2.0.x, but you can navigate to the directory for the control you need and access the html file directly.

Answer (score 9):

You can check all older releases in the link below. Run the respective showcase to find the relevant documentation.

https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/releases

Comment: yep, is seems this is the only reference available online.

Comment: Just wish it was really online :/